# Creating custom unit for sass

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, sass

I want to create custom css unit, that I'll be able to use in sass with node.js. Is there any guide about creating sass plugin for this? Just for example, I want to create unit "dpx",  that will work as double pixel, so "width: 20dpx" will be processed to "width: 40px".

Other solution (not sass plugin), that can work with node is also acceptable.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a SASS function that accepts a font-size and returns the value doubled.

```
@function dpx($size) {
  @return $size * 2;
}

div {
  font-size: dpx(20px);  // output: font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need exactly custom unit, but not sass function. It's because real task is more complicated, than example. I also need use values of other fields in selector to count current. And I need not to pass all of them all the time

Answer (score 1):

As a simplified version of the current answer, you could also write the following:

```
$d: 2px;

div { font-size: 20*$d; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but since I found it, other people will find it too.
In such case as yours a good solution would be to make a 1rem equal to 2px.
You can do it this way:

```
html {
  font-size: 2px;
}
```

now each 1rem will be equal to 2px. If you want to make sure this doesn't break your current page, you can always add

```
body {
  font-size: 8rem;
}
```

to set the global font-size to 16px (just a guess since this is a default value).